# Pie menu and limited viewport shading options (show subset of an enum)

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

So most code exmaples I find are using the option to list all shading options

```
pie.prop(context.space_data, "viewport_shade", expand=True)
```

But I would like to only show 3 and have the feeling that I have to create a new
class operator to execute the code like:

```
bpy.context.space_data.viewport_shade = 'SOLID'
```

Am right with that assumption?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nope, to display a subset of an enum you can use `wm.context_set_enum`

```
        f = pie.operator("wm.context_set_enum", icon='SOLID', text='Solid')
        f.data_path='space_data.viewport_shade'
        f.value = 'SOLID'

        f = pie.operator("wm.context_set_enum", icon='WIRE', text='Wires')
        f.data_path='space_data.viewport_shade'
        f.value = 'WIREFRAME'
```

[image]

You might use a loop to reuse some code:

```
        modes = [
            ["SOLID", "SOLID", "Solid"],
            ["WIRE", "WIREFRAME", "Wires"],
            ["BBOX", "BOUNDBOX", "Bounds"]
        ]

        for ICON, VALUE, TEXT in modes:
            f = pie.operator("wm.context_set_enum", icon=ICON, text=TEXT)
            f.data_path='space_data.viewport_shade'
            f.value = VALUE
```

Comment: Grrrr Just text is what you can use for the type - I would not have guessed that.

Comment: Do you have a paypal account?

Comment: oh wow - RENDERED does not have an icon you can select?!?!

Comment: Yeah that's what I imagined and I use that icon as well already. Are you in Russia? Any other service? You help me so much.

Comment: LOL - the icon the RENDERED mode uses is called "SMOOTH"